# Tinymce using justboilme plugin - dynamic file config

Tags: php, tinymce, justboil.me

I am using tinymce in my project with the justboilme plugin so that I could save images in a certain location on the server. In the config file, I did the following and worked fine:

```
$config['img_path'] = 'public/photos'; // Relative to domain name
$config['upload_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $config['img_path']; // Physical path.
```

The questions is, If I have multiple folders to save my files on the server side (users, projects...etc) How can I dynamically change the config so that the file get uploaded in the correct directory.

Example:

- *Uploading user photo -> gets uploaded in users folder*
- *Uploading project photo -> get uploaded in projects folder*

Is that possible?

Comment: +1 The poor plugin documentation does not state out if that is possible. Assuming not, searching for that simple feature too!